# How do I animate a element when clicking a button with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, this

I am currently learning jQuery and am trying to workout how I would add a class to a span when someone clicks inside one the text input field in my form, and it also doesn't apply the class to all of the spans when only one of the inputs is clicked.

At the moment I have this code, which does add the class, but when I click inside one of the text input fields it adds the .active class it to all of the inputs.

```
$(".form input").click(function(){
  $("span").addClass("active");
});
```

I understand that I have to use $(this), but I can't quite figure out the syntax as it isn't clicking yet.

Thanks for any help

EDIT

Sorry I should have included more of my code. I have added a link to a website with what I am trying to achieve. When you click on one of the inputs in the form the label for that input moves up so you can enter the text. I have also noticed that if you don't enter anything then the label moves back down again.

Website: [Website link](http://travisneilson.com/#notes)

Thanks for the replies so far

Comment: `".form input"` is not a button.

Comment: We need to see your HTML

Comment: _"I am trying to workout how I would add a class to an input when a button"_ `span` element appear to have `class` added at `$("span").addClass("active");` ? Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: without the html we cant help you

Comment: @MarGera332 `.form` element not appear at http://travisneilson.com/#notes ?

Answer (score 0):

> currently learning jQuery and I am trying to workout how I would add a
>   class to an input when a button is clicked

```
$(".form input[type=button]").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply guest. What I need to do is add that class to a span when you click on a form input, but only that span and not the others.

Comment: @MarGera332 Can include `html` text from "Website link" at Question text ? , create stacksnippets http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: has the link taken you through to the notes page? On that page there are two fields one "Your First Name" and the other "Your Email address". Also I am checking out jsfiddle and the create stack snippets link :) Thanks